# Quick 'if-else' flipping in Intellij shortcut

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to refactor existing legacy code and I noticed that I have many places with below pattern:

```
if (condition) {
    // lot of code
} else {
    throw new SomeException();
}
```

I was wondering if there is a fast way of flipping if-else construct to easily refactor current form to something like this:

```
if(!condition) throw new SomeException();
// lot of code
```

I want to remove unnecessary nesting and making checks at the begining of the function.

Comment: alt-enter on the statement, it should give you a few options

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Put the caret on 'if', press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, select "Invert 'if' condition" from the menu.

Comment: I wish they'd allow tips on this site, because I'd totally tip you for this answer.  This is going to save me soooo much time.

Comment: Works really nice with Java, it even magical simplify conditions, inverting `if (!foo && !bar)` gives out `if (foo || bar)`, using Javascript though, it just blindly goes `if (!(!foo && !bar))` :(

Answer (score 16):

For *on the spot editing*, use @Yole's suggestion.

However, if you have many places throughout the project, you can use [`Edit` => `Find` => `Replace structurally`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace-examples.html) with the following templates (deduced from the samples shipped with IJ and tested with v2017.3.4):

**Search template:**

```
if ($Condition$) {
  $ThenStatement$;
} else {
  throw new $Constructor$($Argument$);
}
```

**Replacement template**

```
if (!$Condition$) throw new $Constructor$($Argument$);

$ThenStatement$;
```

**Variables**:

Click the `Edit variables` button, then select the `ThenStatement` variable and check the `Unlimited` box so it applies to multiple lines (or type whatever value you require):

[image: Variables]

**Result**

[image: IJ Structural Replace]

Comment: This is incredible, you should have more upvotes... Thank you.

Comment: @TomaszBawor You're welcome, and yeah there are some awesome things your IDE can do ([here's some more pro-tips](https://medium.com/@andrey_cheptsov/intellij-idea-pro-tips-6da48acafdb7)). As for the votes, that depends whether the audience finds this to their liking :-) At the same time, if this solves your problem, it's good enough for me

Comment: Awesome answer!

Comment: Too bad we cannot vote twice. Your answer is just completing the response from @Yole's.